# Apostrophe in String

Tags: swift, string

I have looked over several threads discussing apostrophe replacement in swift and most of them tell folks that the single quote on the keyboard (on the same key as the double quote) is not the same as an apostrophe. While I understand that, I still need to find and replace single quotes in my string because they are breaking down a process I have where I send them over a URL. So does anyone know why this code doesn't find the single quote?

```
let newString = oldString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\'", with: "%27")
```

I have also tried:

```
let newString = oldString.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "%27")
```

And neither seem to work.

Comment: Because it's not that character? Could it be this one: `’` instead of `'`? Or the one there: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html (U+2018/U+2019), but I think I wrote the 2018 one) If you don't show `oldString`, that's hard to guess...

Comment: Are you sure it's not a "smart quote" character? If this is coming from a text field, just disable smart quotes on it.

Comment: Don't manually try to replace the character. Use the provided methods to properly encode a URL.

Comment: Can you list any of the provided methods here? I will try them and let you know if they work. Again this is the character that is on the same key as the double quote so I would think that users would use this key a lot when entering text.

Comment: To @Lame (the first comment) the text in oldString is :
"Don't watch"

And the single quote in Don't is what I'm trying to find and replace.

Comment: Well I've solved 99% of this problem. The solution was to do a for loop through each character of the string and get the character's ascii code with this:

    let asciiCode = c.unicodeScalars[c.unicodeScalars.startIndex].value

Then you can do an if comparison on asciiCode and if it is 8217 then you are dealing with a single quote and can start cutting substrings and pasting in %27 for it. To do this I used a recursive function I wrote. First time I've ever don't that since high school CS class! Oh yeah, the reason I said 99% is because it doesn't work when there's a space before the '